# Ebean - Find by part of UUID in UUID column Type

Tags: java, playframework, orm, uuid, ebean

from Historical reasons we have ORM Model as bellow with several UUID values. Yes, I know.. We have to implement new frontend for users, where user can write only part of UUID (printed on boxs, papers etc..) Its used for manual verification (Q&A in Factory). Normally this is done with the QR reader, but in some cases it is not possible to scan it. So user can write first 10 chars or 6 last chars...

!! -> And we cannot change anything on this model. (Corporation...)

```
public class Model_OrderCross {

   public UUID id;
   public UUID order_a;
   public UUID order_b;
   public UUID order_c;
   public UUID order_e;
}
```

Why I am Asking. We have Exception with wrong argument types from Ebean when we are trying to find list of objects with this part of UUID

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
Cause message: ERROR: function lower(uuid) does not exist
  Rada: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I am using ORM query:

```
Query<Model_OrderCross > query = Ebean.find(Model_OrderCross.class);

// Where order_b is something like "f223274c-51" from Full UUID "f223274c-51ca-4489-a5b2-7d3b29887cfb" 
if (request.order_b != null) {       
    query.where().icontains("order_b", request. order_b);
}

if (request.order_c != null) {       
    query.where().icontains("order_c", request. order_c);
}
```

- And for normal String or Text values  **..icontains(..)** work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PostgreSQL documentation Section [9.4. String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) (Table 9.8), the function `lower(string)` accepts string literals and "Converts [a] string to lower case" representation.

As the exception message says,

> ERROR: function lower(uuid) does not exist.

So you have to formulate the criteria queries to take a string representation of the `UUID` values, e.g.:

```
query.where().icontains("order_b", request. order_b.toString());
```

This should do the trick. Note well the `toString()` at the end which conducts the conversion to a string literal. The details of the conversion is described in the JavaDoc of [`UUID.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString()).

For reference, I add the link to the JavaDoc of the [`ExpressionList.icontains()`](https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidoc/10/io/ebean/ExpressionList.html#icontains-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method which you applied in the code snippet. Internally, it "uses a `lower()` function to make the expression case insensitive".

Hope it helps.